# REPLACE function evaluated within an IN clause does not work in Oracle SQL 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem where a replace function evaluated within an in clause does not work in Oracle SQL 11g. What I need is a SQL based work around as all I have control of is the SQL.

I recieve a list of values pipe delimited e.g `STR1|STR2`. To convert them to a list of values to query on I use replace as below and should get a result of 1 to this query.

```
select 1 from dual where 'STR1' in (replace('''STR1|STR2''','|',''','''))
```

In fact I get no rows returned. The replace is syntactically corrct and 
esentially this should be resolving down to

```
select 1 from dual where 'STR1' in ('STR1','STR2')
```

which would get the result I want; but it doesn't work with the replace.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing the pipe will still leave you with a single string literal with `'STR1','STR2'`, not two separate list elements. Replace just doesn't do what you want, in an IN clause or anywhere else. The IN still just sees a single string value and that doesn't match your search string.

You could tokenise your delimited string; this is a common method:

```
with t as (
  select regexp_substr('STR1|STR2', '[^|]+', level) as str
  from dual
  connect by regexp_substr('STR1|STR2', '[^|]+', level) is not null
)
select 1 from dual where 'STR1' in (select str from t)
```

The CTE gets the two list elements as separate rows, and you can then use a subquery to see if your value is in that list.

Or more simply use `regexp_like` to look for your value between delimiters, allowing for it being at the start or the end:

```
select 1 from dual where regexp_like('STR1|STR2', '(^|)' || 'STR1' || '(|$)');
```

Or without regular expressions, if you wrap your value in delimiters:

```
select 1 from dual where '|' || 'STR1|STR2' || '|' like '%|' || 'STR1' || '|%';
```

You don't need all that concatenation with fixed values, but I assume you're actually getting both strings from somewhere else, and this might make it clearer how it's constructing the comparisons. (Though the pipe delimiter makes it look more confusing too...)

Comment: Thanks Alex, not sure I understanding that though. How can that be integratted within a single SQL statement please? This condition will be part of a much larger single query. No PLSQL or language involved.cheers Dave

Comment: Sorry, just seen edit, will have a go with the regexp_like

Comment: Cheers Alex, regexp_like seems to do the trick. Thanks very much for your help. I'll mark your answer as correct. cheers, Dave

Comment: @MrTea - there's no PL/SQL involved in the first option, just subquery factoring (the CTE). You may be able to do that with a large query but it is likely to be confusing. The second or third options are probably more suitable; if it's a big query check the performance of both though.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and managed to work it this way:

```
SELECT 1 from dual
where 'str1' in (select distinct a.name from 
    (select  trim(substr( the_string 
         , decode( level, 1, 1, instr(the_string,',',1,level-1)+1) 
         , decode( instr(the_string,',',1,level), 0, length(the_string), instr(the_string,',',1,level) - decode( level, 1, 0, instr(the_string,',',1,level-1))-1) 
         )) name
from ( select replace('str1|str2','|',',') the_string , 
     replace('str1|srt2','|',',') the_string1 
     FROM dual ) 
     connect by level <= length(the_string)-length(replace(the_string,','))+1) a)
```